# Update an array into database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

For my codes, When I select the checkbox, it will retrieve the date and price from database and do a calculation to get a total price.

But it update all rows with the same value.

I had tried to select 3 checkbox, and var_dump the total price, and the results are correct.

But I want to update into database, it updated all rows with the same value.

Controller:

```
            $PledgeCheckbox =  ($this->input->post('batch_pledge[]')  ? '1' : '0');
            //$Pledge_No = $this->input->post('batch_pledge[]'); //return value of pledge_id

            if($PledgeCheckbox == '1'){
                $Pledge_No = $this->input->post('batch_pledge[]'); //return value of pledge_id

                //take the stg_fee_per_mth from database and calculate $Total_Stg_Fee
                $Pledge = $this->pledge->GetPledgeStgFee($Pledge_No);
                foreach($Pledge as $row){
                    $Stg_fee_per_mth = $row->stg_fee_per_mth;
                    $Pledge_date = $row->pledge_date;

                    $DATE_NOW = strtotime($Cur_date);
                    $DATE_PREV = strtotime($Pledge_date);

                    $Year1 = date('y', $DATE_NOW);
                    $Year2 = date('y', $DATE_PREV);

                    $Month_Now = date('m', $DATE_NOW);
                    $Month_Prev = date('m', $DATE_PREV);

                    $Month_diff = (($Year1 - $Year2)*12)+($Month_Now - $Month_Prev);

                    if($Month_diff !== 0){
                        $Total_Stg_Fee = $Stg_fee_per_mth * $Month_diff;

                        //update $Total_Stg_fee in database
                        $this->pledge->UpdatePledgeTotalStgFee($Total_Stg_Fee,$Month_diff);
                        //var_dump($Total_Stg_Fee);
                    }else{
                        //if $Month_diff == 0, $Stg_fee_per_mth must multiple with 1, if not $Total_stg_Fee will become 0
                        $Month_diff = 1;
                        $Total_Stg_Fee = $Stg_fee_per_mth * 1;

                        //update $Total_Stg_fee in database
                        $this->pledge->UpdatePledgeTotalStgFee($Total_Stg_Fee,$Month_diff);

                        //var_dump($Total_Stg_Fee);
                    }

                }
                $data['pledge'] = $this->pledge->FetchPledge2Renew($Pledge_No);
                $this->load->view('auth/header',$data);
                $this->load->view('pledge/batch_renew_pledge',$data);
                $this->load->view('pledge/footer',$data);
            }
```

Model:

```
    public function UpdatePledgeTotalStgFee($Total_Stg_Fee,$Month_diff){
        $post = $this->input->post();
        //$Month_diff = $post;
        //$Total_Stg_Fee = $post;

        foreach($post['batch_pledge'] as $k => $value){
        $TotalStgFee[] = array(
                                'pledge_id' => $value,
                                'no_of_mth' => $Month_diff,
                                'total_stg_fee' => $Total_Stg_Fee                 
                             );
        }
        $this->db->update_batch('pledge',$TotalStgFee,'pledge_id'); //('table','array','condition')
    }
```

output of var_dump($TotalStgFee)

```
C:\wamp64\www\kde\store\application\models\Pledge_model.php:683:
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'pledge_id' => string '27' (length=2)
      'no_of_mth' => int 1
      'total_stg_fee' => float 20
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'pledge_id' => string '21' (length=2)
      'no_of_mth' => int 1
      'total_stg_fee' => float 20
C:\wamp64\www\kde\store\application\models\Pledge_model.php:683:
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'pledge_id' => string '27' (length=2)
      'no_of_mth' => int 36
      'total_stg_fee' => float 900
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'pledge_id' => string '21' (length=2)
      'no_of_mth' => int 36
      'total_stg_fee' => float 900
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug your code? Where **exactly** is it going wrong?

Comment: @NicoHaase 1 pledge_id only got 1 no_of_mth and  1 total_stg_fee, but when I var_dump, it shown 2 id 2 no_of_mth and 2total_stg_fee

Answer (score 0):

To iterate a posted checkbox input, it's better to use `foreach` instead of `for` loop since the `$post['pledge_id']` array index is not always sequential. I've changed your codes to just call the update method only once after the `foreach` loop :

*Controller* :

```
$PledgeCheckbox =  ($this->input->post('batch_pledge[]')  ? '1' : '0');
//$Pledge_No = $this->input->post('batch_pledge[]'); //return value of pledge_id

if($PledgeCheckbox == '1'){
    $Pledge_No = $this->input->post('batch_pledge[]'); //return value of pledge_id

    //take the stg_fee_per_mth from database and calculate $Total_Stg_Fee
    $Pledge = $this->pledge->GetPledgeStgFee($Pledge_No);
    if (!empty($Pledge)) {
        $Total_Stg_Fee = [];
        $Month_diff = [];
        foreach($Pledge as $k => $row){
            $Stg_fee_per_mth = $row->stg_fee_per_mth;
            $Pledge_date = $row->pledge_date;

            $DATE_NOW = strtotime($Cur_date);
            $DATE_PREV = strtotime($Pledge_date);

            $Year1 = date('y', $DATE_NOW);
            $Year2 = date('y', $DATE_PREV);

            $Month_Now = date('m', $DATE_NOW);
            $Month_Prev = date('m', $DATE_PREV);

            $Month_diff[$k] = (($Year1 - $Year2)*12)+($Month_Now - $Month_Prev);

            if($Month_diff[$k] !== 0){
                $Total_Stg_Fee[$k] = $Stg_fee_per_mth * $Month_diff[$k];

                //update $Total_Stg_fee in database
                // $this->pledge->UpdatePledgeTotalStgFee($Total_Stg_Fee,$Month_diff);
                //var_dump($Total_Stg_Fee);
            }else{
                //if $Month_diff == 0, $Stg_fee_per_mth must multiple with 1, if not $Total_stg_Fee will become 0
                $Month_diff[$k] = 1;
                $Total_Stg_Fee[$k] = $Stg_fee_per_mth * 1;

                //update $Total_Stg_fee in database
                // $this->pledge->UpdatePledgeTotalStgFee($Total_Stg_Fee,$Month_diff);

                //var_dump($Total_Stg_Fee);
            }
        }
        $this->pledge->UpdatePledgeTotalStgFee($Pledge_No,$Total_Stg_Fee,$Month_diff);
    }
    $data['pledge'] = $this->pledge->FetchPledge2Renew($Pledge_No);
    $this->load->view('auth/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('pledge/batch_renew_pledge',$data);
    $this->load->view('pledge/footer',$data);
}
```

*Model* :

```
public function UpdatePledgeTotalStgFee($Pledge_No,$Total_Stg_Fee,$Month_diff){
    // $post = $this->input->post();
    //$Month_diff = $post;
    //$Total_Stg_Fee = $post;
    // $arraySize = count($post['pledge_id']);
    /*
    for($k=0; $k<$arraySize; $k++){
        $TotalStgFee[] = array(
                                'pledge_id' => $post['pledge_id'][$k],
                                'no_of_mth' => $Month_diff.[$k],
                                'total_stg_fee' => $Total_Stg_Fee.[$k]                  
                            );
    }
    */
    $TotalStgFee = [];
    foreach($Pledge_No as $k => $value){
        $TotalStgFee[$k] = array(
                                'pledge_id' => $value,
                                'no_of_mth' => $Month_diff[$k],
                                'total_stg_fee' => $Total_Stg_Fee[$k]
                            );
    }
    $this->db->update_batch('pledge',$TotalStgFee,'pledge_id'); //('table','array','condition')
}
```

This will save each `$Total_Stg_Fee` and `$Month_diff` as an array first, then insert it as batch insert. I've also added `$Pledge_No` as a parameter on the `UpdatePledgeTotalStgFee()` function and passing it to the model.

Comment: I had edited my model above, but i still get the same problems

Comment: What is the content of `$this->input->post('pledge_id') `? And what is the content of `$this->input->post('batch_pledge[]')  `?

Comment: pledge_id is the column in the database, batch_pledge[] contain the pledge_id, I had var_dump the TotalStgFee in the model, you can see the above edited question